# Associations between state and city models

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model-associations

Looking to create a business directory that can be sorted first by state then city (similar to Craigslist).

Should I create a state model and city model separately or created a locations model with both state and city as separate columns in the locations table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with 2 columns: `state` and `city`.

In order to go something like:

`Collection.order('state ASC')` or
`Collection.order('city ASC')`

Depends after on how complex you want the thing to be.